# Calculate averages of stdin in python

Tags: python, average, stdin

I want to read in python from stdin and it looks like this:

```
(Group),(Grade):
1gT,8
1gT,5
1gT,9
1gT,8
1gX,4
1gX,4
1gX,7
1gZ,2
1gZ,9
1gZ,10
```

Now I want to calculate the averages per group.
I know I can read from stdin with

```
for line in sys.stdin:
```

And I know how to calculate the averages:

```
([Sum of all grades from one group] / [number of grades of one group])
```

But how can I read the grades per group and count the number of it in Python3?

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example. What format is your data? A df? A list? etc.? @PdH

Comment: You want to count or average the grade?

Comment: Since you already know how to read the data and how to calculate averages, your *actual* question is "how to split a line at comma" then?

Comment: My data is a list and I want to average the grade per group.

Comment: My question is not how to split a line at comma but how can I read the lines until another group and than calculate a new average

Comment: Who is downvoting all the suggested answers and why! Please give a reason and post your own answer.

Comment: @CiaranOBrien So far none of the answers actually answer the question. One doesn't read the input. One doesn't average all groups. One lights up like a Christmas tree in my IDE because of all the NameErrors.

Comment: @PdH Is the data actually sorted by group, or is it possible that a ``1gT`` will also appear after a ``1gZ``? Is ``(Group),(Grade):`` part of the input? Do you just want to print the result or, say, store it in a dict from group name to average?

Comment: The data is sorted by group and (group),(grade) isn't part of the input

Comment: I want to store it from group name to average

Comment: @MisterMiyagi My answer runs fine. It takes the data as a list, as OP said is the format, and averages the results per group from that list.

Comment: @CiaranOBrien As the question says "I want to read in python from stdin and it looks like this:". That is a list, yes, but not a ``list``.

Comment: It's a list but not a list... Got it.....@MisterMiyagi

Comment: @CiaranOBrien The word list has a general meaning as well. A list is just any listing of things. A Python ``list`` is a specific data type.

Comment: "My data is a list" - OP. @MisterMiyagi

Comment: @CiaranOBrien "I want to read in python from stdin and it looks like this:" – also OP.

Comment: Lets agree to disagree then. @MisterMiyagi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for thinking.
Thanks to Watanabe.N for helping, with a few edits on your answer it worked.

This worked for me:

```js
import sys

ave = 0
total = 0
count = 0
firstline = sys.stdin.readline()
group, grade = firstline.split()
currentGroup = group
grade = int(grade)
total += grade
count += 1

for line in sys.stdin:
    group, grade = line.split()
    grade = int(grade)
    if currentGroup != group:
        print(currentGroup, ave)
        count = 1
        total = 0 + grade
        currentGroup = group
        continue
    count += 1
    total += grade
    ave = total/count
else:
    print(currentGroup, ave)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import pandas as pd

test = ['1gT',8,

'1gT',5,

'1gT',9,

'1gT',8,

'1gX',4,

'1gX',4,

'1gX',7,

'1gZ',2,

'1gZ',9,

'1gZ',10]

# turn list into dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(test) 

# rename column
df = df.rename({0: 'Group'}, axis=1)  

# break out columns using even numbers and odd numbers
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group':df['Group'].iloc[::2].values, 'Value':df['Group'].iloc[1::2].values})

# Change value to int
df['Value'] = df['Value'].apply(pd.to_numeric) 

# group and get results
grouped_df = df.groupby("Group")
mean_df = grouped_df.mean()
```

Here is a rough and ready example.

Comment: This does not read stdin. It already assume the data was read properly.